# Is there a way to say the object only once when I have to use it again and again?

Tags: c++

Take for example:

```
int main(void){
    numberComparator comparator1;

    comparator1.setA(78.321);
    comparator1.showA();
    comparator1.setB('c');
    comparator1.setB("Yes");
    comparator1.setB(124.213);
    comparator1.showB();
    comparator1.setB(12);

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of saying `comparator1` over and over again, can I do something shorter?

I understand that this doesn't really change much about how the program works, but it does make it easier to work around with testing a class I make.

I am doing overloading so that for an assortment of inputs into my comparator, my program can handle them without making the results go crazy. In this case, I want the input to be an `int`, but what if the input isn't?

The answer could be lying around the internet, but as my title may infer, I do not know how to state the question.

Comment: I don't see what you are looking for. You could use a macro, or a function if you want to repeat same code on different objects (or multiple times) but you can't avoid referring to a variable to call a method on it when you are writing your own code. You could make all `setA` `setB` etc methods return a `numberComparator&` so that you can chain them, eg `comparator1.setA(78.321).showA().setB('c')` but then it's just less readable.

Comment: There is no language feature that allows you to do that, and if it is  a problem for you then I would suggest the problem really lies in the design of your classes.

Comment: Is it really that hard to type or copy/paste `comparator1` on each line?

Comment: You can implement the generator pattern, which does exactly what you need. If each of those functions return the object itself (`return this;`), you can affectively chain them together

Comment: You could type in `X` for the variable name when you are typing, then use Search & Replace to change `X` to `comparator1`.

Comment: Then I guess the answer is a straight up no, yes?

Comment: @maja I'll take note of that. It might come in handy in the future. But I can't use it for now.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not really. It is what I have been doing.

Comment: @Jack I understand what you suggested and yes, I agree, it does make it unreadable. But for testing purpose where I delete the code afterwards, that may work well enough for me.

Comment: Another option is to write a single set-function which gets a struct that contains all values. This way, you can set everything with a single call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.  If `numberComparator` has a "fluent" interface, then each member function will return a reference to `*this`, and you can write:

```
    comparator1
        .setA(78.321)
        .showA()
        .setB('c')
        .setB("Yes")
        .setB(124.213)
        .showB()
        .setB(12);
```

Note that this is a bitch to debug by step-into (you have to step into *every* function until you get to the one you are interested in).

The alternative of course is "use a shorter name".

```
int main(void){
    numberComparator c1;

    c1.setA(78.321);
    c1.showA();
    c1.setB('c');
    c1.setB("Yes");
    c1.setB(124.213);
    c1.showB();
    c1.setB(12);

    return 0;
}
```

There is really no point in having a particularly long name if it is limited in scope to a few lines.  For a local variable, if it isn't limited in scope to a few lines, your function is probably too long.

Comment: I hate it when people do things like that "fluent" interface, as you call it. It is also very hard to do const-correctly.

Comment: @SergeyA Things like what?  "Fluent interface" or "use short name".  I quite like fluent interfaces for "set arbitrary members of a struct with default values".

Comment: I will try this "fluent" interface you say, and yes, shorter names. Just a bad habit of mine.

Comment: "fluent" interface with a mixture of set/non-set functions as in your example.

Comment: @A.Ortiga don't overdo it with shorter names, though. there's broad area between too long and incomprehensible alphabet soup. Try to drop inside that region somewhere.

Comment: Oh well. If I just wanted to make the whole code less tiring to type in, which is, even in my opinion, absurd, because coding is basically typing, I should really just shorten the names.

Comment: @user4581301 True, true.

Comment: I don't hate it when people do "fluent" interface, so downvoted for a different reason.

Comment: @anatolyg It would be helpful if you were prepared to explain the downvote - it might enable me to improve my answer.

Comment: @A.Ortiga "coding is basically typing" - you will find that you spend *much* more of your time when programming *reading* code than typing.  The general rule is to make it as easy as possible to understand, not easy to type.

Comment: @MartinBonner I see. I learn more and more here than in school. Honestly. Thanks for the heads-up. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for something like `with` keyword which is part of, for example, Pascal language.

Unfortunately, C++ doesn't provide similar feature. Using the references, one can shorten the name of the class and somewhat alleviate the pain, i.e.

```
Comparator comparator1;
...
{
    Comparator& cr = comparator1;

    cr.a();
    cr.b();
    cr.c();
}
```

Comment: If the point of the code `Comparator& cr = comparator1;` is to shorten the name, I guess I'll just have to shorten the actual name itself then. Still, something new, so +1.